# CGAL 3D Mesh: how to ensure there are always at least two elements between the opposite sides of the domain?

Tags: mesh, cgal, tetrahedra

I am using the CGAL package [3D Mesh generation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html) to convert a triangulated model of a turbine blade into a tetrahedral mesh. However, my downstream application requires at least two tetrahedra between the opposite sides of the domain. Unless I set `edge_size` in `Mesh_criteria` very low, I get a mesh containing a tetrahedral element connecting the opposing sides of the domain, which makes the downstream application unhappy.

Is there a possibility to modify, for instance, the [mesh_polyhedral_domain_with_features.cpp](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2mesh_polyhedral_domain_with_features_8cpp-example.html) example to ensure this? I seem to remember that there was such an option in [MeshGems-Tetra](http://www.meshgems.com/volume-meshing-meshgems-tetra.html) (which seems similar in function to this CGAL package) but so far I was unable to find anything in CGAL.

Comment: Just FYI, there is [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh#volume-meshes-from-surface-meshes) which makes working with CGAL a fair bit easier. I don't have an actual answer to your problem though. You're probably best off on the CGAL mailing list.